# Unable to play proprietary media formats even after installing restricted extras 

Tags: multimedia, gstreamer, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. I am unable to play proprietary media formats on Ubuntu Precise even after installing Ubuntu-Restricted-Extras. I am using Totem and Rhytmbox as my players.

Comment: Can you try playing a file, and explain exactly what happens. Post any errors there are, and if you aren't able to do some or any of that, perhaps explain why not.

Comment: even after installing the restricted extra there are some particular formats which are not played... by the way which are the ones you are facing problem with? Try using VLC for video formats..

Comment: The term "proprietary media formats" covers a lot of things. Could you be more specific? Seeing Totem, Rhythmbox and VLC makes me think: commercial DVDs. The surest thing for this is to add the Medibuntu Repository (http://medibuntu.org/repository.php) and get the package libdvdcss2 from there.

Comment: I an trying to play a mp4 file in totem player and it is simply not playing. Totem is executing but the video is not playing. No warning or message is coming. I tried the same with other video files, but same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` and it should play fine.

Comment: Its installed with Ubuntu Restricted Extras.

Comment: Do you have gstreamer0.10-plugins-good installed?

Comment: Yes I also did sudo apt-get -f install. It showed zero changes.

Comment: OK. They play fine here. Perhaps you are hitting some bug then and should open a bug report by running "ubuntu-bug totem" in a terminal for example. I don't think there's any simple answer to be had on askUbuntu at this point.

Answer (score 1):

this code fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gnonlin gstreamer0.10-sdl gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-schroedinger gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem-plugins-extra
```

[source](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/to-do-list-after-installing-ubuntu-12-04-lts-aka-precise-pangolin/)